# SDL2 based game and GADBannerView

Tags: c++, ios, gadbannerview

Now I'm working at SDL2 based game for iOS and I have a question.
How to implement Google advertising banner in my case?

Answer (score 0):

One year later...
The answer to this question you can find in my blog [AdMob implementation in SDL2-based games](http://blog.lapingames.com/admob-implementation-in-sdl2-based-games/). I hope this will help someone.